# C/C++ functions returning NaN in MonoTouch when p/invoked

Tags: c#, c++, c, xamarin.ios, pinvoke

I have two source files:

File.h:

```
class Numbers
{
public:
    int Get10();
    int Get192();   
    float GetFloat();
};
```

File.cpp:

```
int Numbers::Get10()
{
    return 10;
}
int Numbers::Get192()
{
    return 192;
}
float Numbers::GetFloat()
{
    return 3213.1294124f;
}

extern "C"
int Get10()
{
    Numbers n;
    return n.Get10();
}

extern "C"
int Get192()
{
    Numbers n;
    return n.Get192();
}

extern "C"
int GetFloat()
{
    Numbers n;
    return n.GetFloat();
}
```

I compile these into a static library (libNumbers.a) and link it in with MonoTouch via the following mtouch arguments:

> -v -v -v -gcc_flags "-cxx -framework Security -L${ProjectDir}
>   -lNumbers -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libNumbers.a"

Then in the C# source file I have this:

```
    [DllImport("__Internal",EntryPoint="GetFloat")]
    public static extern float GetFloat();
```

When I call GetFloat() from inside the C# source file the value returned in 'NaN' instead of 3213.1294124f. If I call Get10 however I actually get the correct value returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe changing the return type of this function to `float` is the way to go?

```
extern "C"
int GetFloat()
{
    Numbers n;
    return n.GetFloat();
}
```

Comment: well spotted! Pity it doesn't solve my problem :( still getting NaN from GetFloat, I even get NAN from Get10 so I don't think it has something to do with the functions themselves.

Comment: @meds, actually, how exactly do you get NAN for integer values? Please provide the declarations for other functions in C# code.

Comment: @meds, wait a sec again, in the question you say that `Get10` yields correct result. Please, clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I just found out my mistake was in how I declared the function in C#, once I amended the C++ source file as per your answer I had forgotten that I had changed the return time of the extern function to int in the C# file and that caused me to get confused. Suffice to say your answer actually was the solution to my problem but I got confused hence why the mix up. Sorry about that!